# Memory mapped file value is set to zero after read access

Tags: c#, python, ipc, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I want to achieve interprocess communication between Python and C# in order to read values in my C# application which are written by a Python script.
In C#, I am using the MemoryMappedFile class:

```
MemoryMappedFile mmfSimPro = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MyFileMappingObject_SimPro", 20);
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessorAxesSimPro = mmfSimPro.CreateViewAccessor(0, 20);
for (int i = 0; i < axesSimPro.Length; i++)
   axesSimPro[i] = accessorAxesSimPro.ReadSingle(sizeof(float) * i);
```

It reads the values successfully, but after that it sets the values in the memory mapped file to zero. So if I read the memory mapped file again (and it hasn't been overwritten by the Python script yet), I will read only zeros. How can I prevent that?

My python script looks as follows:

```
def WriteAxes():
  shmem = mmap.mmap(0,256, "MyFileMappingObject_SimPro",mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
  struct.pack_into('f',shmem,0,_ctrl.Joints[1].CurrentValue)
  struct.pack_into('f',shmem,4,_ctrl.Joints[0].CurrentValue)
  struct.pack_into('f',shmem,8,_ctrl.Joints[2].CurrentValue)
  struct.pack_into('f',shmem,12,_ctrl.Joints[3].CurrentValue)
  struct.pack_into('f',shmem,16,_ctrl.Joints[4].CurrentValue-90)
  shmem.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `.CreateOrOpen` you are using a Non-Pesisted MemoryMappedFile ( see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx) *which means the GC is free to GC the contents*

I am making some assumptions about the rest of your code but it looks like you CreateOrOpen and read in a single method,  thus the GC is free to dispose the contents as soon as you have finished reading,  basically this is some memory your C# app owns and it will be GCed as normal.

You would need either to `.CreateOrOpen` in some wider context of A (ie it is opened (and kept referenced) at app startup or in whatever appropriate 'session' object) or move to `.CreateFromFile` to view it as persistent (perhaps with some manual zeroing out at the begining if that is needed / appropriate).

TLDR; `mmfSimPro` should probably be held at app / class level in a field not in a local variable so it has a live GC handle for the app / class lifetime and NOT just for the length of the read method.